# IE 8 unable to redirect to relative path

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-8

In my SSO service I'm redirecting the incoming request after validation which response message is

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: /home?s=ZXVuPXN0YWZmdXNyMDE7ZXVwPXN0QGZmdXNSMDE7b2ZmaWNlaWQ9O29mZmljZT07Y3VzdD1PSzt0cz03MzUyNjIwNDIwO3ZlbmRvcj0xO3N1bj1zZWVrZXIwN0BkZW1vLmNvbTs=
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 27 Jan 2014 09:20:36 GMT
Content-Length: 261

<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/home?s=ZXVuPXN0YWZmdXNyMDE7ZXVwPXN0QGZmdXNSMDE7b2ZmaWNlaWQ9O29mZmljZT07Y3VzdD1PSzt0cz03MzUyNjIwNDIwO3ZlbmRvcj0xO3N1bj1zZWVrZXIwN0BkZW1vLmNvbTs=">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

The above 302 message happens after bunch of redirects between client and server i have listed it below using fiddler

```
#   Result  Protocol    Host    URL Body    Caching Content-Type    Process Comments    Custom  
4   302 HTTPS   client.net  /ok/r/oauth/authorize?client_id=bededeb806f783b75ef94ad871a4e03e2c7aeb1fb316d8822233afaa664d17cb&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.sso.com%2FOKJobMatch.aspx&state=hk1udegmnspyvum5obcwscwe&response_type=code 232 no-cache, private   text/html; charset=utf-8    iexplore:5324           
Suceeded
6   301 HTTPS   example.sso.com /OKJobMatch.aspx?code=c4ee0346f27db36ea662b1d14d3adc6ba6d33e11c3a9dddf759619cf778b0b24&state=hk1udegmnspyvum5obcwscwe   317 private     text/html; charset=utf-8    iexplore:5324           
Suceeded
8   302 HTTPS   example.com /home?s=ZXVuPXN0YWZmdXNyMDE7ZXVwPXN0QGZmdXNSMDE7b2ZmaWNlaWQ9O29mZmljZT07Y3VzdD1PSzt0cz03MzUyNjQwNTQzO3ZlbmRvcj0xO3N1bj1zZWVrZXIwN0BkZW1vLmNvbTs=    261 private     text/html; charset=utf-8    iexplore:5324           
Suceeded with response which mentioned above in the question

9   404 HTTPS   client.net  /home?s=ZXVuPXN0YWZmdXNyMDE7ZXVwPXN0QGZmdXNSMDE7b2ZmaWNlaWQ9O29mZmljZT07Y3VzdD1PSzt0cz03MzUyNjQwNTQzO3ZlbmRvcj0xO3N1bj1zZWVrZXIwN0BkZW1vLmNvbTs=    0           iexplore:5324           
Failed
```

Now all the other browsers including IE 9,10 and Chrome, Mozilla was able to understand this and redirect appropriately but IE 8 is not able to redirect, but it throws a 404 error.

**On further analysis**

we have found that once the 302 message is delivered IE is using the domain of client URL instead the server URL

So instead of going to https://example.com/home
It is going to http://client.net.home. this looks strange because example.com is the one which delivered the redirection message.

Is this something to do with the referrer attribute of http message because i noticed that the referrer is set in the client message

Clients Request after redirection [which genarates the 404 error]

```
GET https://client.net/home?s=ZXVuPXN0YWZmdXNyMDE7ZXVwPXN0QGZmdXNSMDE7b2ZmaWNlaWQ9O29mZmljZT07Y3VzdD1PSzt0cz03MzUyNjUwNDM4O3ZlbmRvcj0xO3N1bj1zZWVrZXIwN0BkZW1vLmNvbTs= HTTP/1.1
Accept: image/jpeg, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-application, application/xaml+xml, application/x-ms-xbap, */*
Referer: https://deployment.ajla.net/ok/mn_loginstatistics_dsp.cfm
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: deployment.ajla.net
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Cookie: _ga=GA1.3.502780954.1391010694; CFID=90758; CFTOKEN=4b494a1b21bbdc06-D9196ABC-FAE3-1AFE-97F781B8328159A0; TEST=1; USAGE_BYPASS=A819843C5390612C307C2E9A433D04101C64C9842FB41146ECFE739EDEDB13F4D692A9A537C758E1F5548B2306170514FAE5F13FF767A436FD24140F4B90F6A2; AJLAUTHSESSION=D93D4D42-ABAC-D007-DC3A2A48361A041C; _joblink_session=BAh7B0kiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFRkkiJTg2MTlkMDZmZjZhMDIwODhkZWJhMjIxODNiN2I2NTNmBjsAVEkiDHVzZXJfaWQGOwBGaQNZnRk%3D--8592abe6d424b90671f013da99d74a1df8e84a33
```

for the same scenario mozilla and other browsers choose www.example.com as the domain. Is this because of the referrer attribute, if yes is there a way to fix it in client code ?

**EDIT 2**

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

I noticed that during first redirection from client site to our site there are two 302 happens first one returns a relative path. Second one returns a absolute path. the second one is generated from source but the first one is not from source. I'm not sure where this redirection happens. I suspect this could have happened because of http redirection set on the site. but im not sure anyway just pasted the http redirection settings above.

can someone tell is there is any workaround to do this ?

Comment: What kind of workaround? You mean a change to IE8 configuration?

Comment: workaround could be instead to returning relative is it a way return the full path like Response.Redirect returns relative path is there way to return like http//:example.com/home/s=sdfsdf ??

Comment: @JohnSaunders Is there any configuration change that could make IE 8 to recognize this ??

Comment: No, this isn't the sort of thing that changes based on configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used a workaround for fixing this issue, i know it may not be a legitimate solution but i don't have no other option to make this work in IE8

```
 protected void Application_EndRequest()
        {
            if (Context.Response.StatusCode == 302)
            {

                if (Context.Response.RedirectLocation.ToLower().StartsWith("/home") && Request.Params.Get("s") != null)
                {
                    Context.Response.RedirectLocation = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.OriginalString;
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since all browsers will understand absolute paths, return an absolute path. We won't be able to change IE8.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your SSO handler works, you could use the [`Response.Redirect( ... )`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524309.aspx) function to redirect the browser. This function will take a relative URI using the `"~/path/to/file"` notation.

Comment: ...which is true, but has nothing to do with the question. The tilde is translated by ASP.NET to an absolute path.

Comment: The question was for a workaround to use relative paths, this is one. The method takes relative paths, which means it works even if your site runs on a folder or has multiple domains, etc, which is exactly what was asked for.

Comment: No browser works with the tilde, they dont know what is the root url of the application, but asp.net does. And it's an asp.net question and answer. I dont see your problem.

Comment: as you can see in the response message of the question the path returned by Response.redirect is /home which is indeed a relative path which IE 8 is not able to redirect to. Is there a way to make my web application to return the full path ??

Comment: Can you add to your question how the 302 response message is created?

Comment: @WillemDuncan I have added the previous transaction which led to this error in the question. Please let me know if you need any other info

Comment: @WillemDuncan I have also pasted the http message of the client which fails and updated my further findings and you please check and tell if this helps ?

Comment: On the server side, how do you generate the redirect message?

Comment: during the first request from server to client the server will validate the user and depending on the status the server will redirect the user to a specific page, this is handled in the source and generates a absolute path during redirection, but it looks there is some other thing which triggers a 302 before the source, i think this might be http to https redirection which is set for site in IIS. I have added the http redirection code above